# Blocking bruteforce attack by modifying htaccess with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, brute-force, ddos

Is it acceptable (and possible)  to automatically block an ip address by modifying .htaccess file dynamically  in php when a bruteforce or DoS attack is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to block an IP. but it's pointless to try to stop a DDos attack this way since the apache process is already spawned.

```
Deny from xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When blocking an IP you would normally enter a rule in the firewall to block that IP out.

I'd suggest you take a look at The apache security module

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu

Also fail2ban is a good way to stop bruteforce attacks.

https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security

Comment: It should be mentioned that stopping a DoS attack using htaccess is completely pointless, because the apache process is already spawned (which is generally the goal of such attacks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the attack is happening on a shared server (shared hosting on siteground)  so I can't install any of the suggested modules/programs but I am talking to support about mod_security. I am also taking other precautions. It's a magento app so I have changed the path to the login page.