# prevent bruteforce with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there an opportunity to prevent bruteforce with htaccess authentification?
For example define a maximum number of trials?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970945/blocking-bruteforce-attack-by-modifying-htaccess-with-php) just showing how to deny access from a specific IP.

Comment: There are strategies based on rate limits, but that rarely works, since most such attacks are organized on a distributed principle these days. Which means you would have to limit _all_ access which also includes acceptable requests.

Comment: I don't think any of the available modules related to HTTP auth (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#related) have anything like that implemented. So short of writing your own Apache module to handle this, this won't be possible. Unless you switch to having all of your content (the one that needs protecting, at least) delivered not directly by the web server itself, but by a script, for example in PHP or python. [...]

Comment: [...] That script would then handle the part of prompting the user for credentials, and checking them - and then you are free to implement whatever additional restrictions you want, like keep a counter & last attempt for each username in a database, or something like that. And if your limit of attempts for that specific username is reached, have the script respond with forbidden no matter what credentials were actually provided.